# In Chrome alert is not showing, In IE working fine

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

> In Chrome alert is not showing, In IE working fine. While click on other tab in chrome refreshing the tab because of ajax call, I want keep ajax call as it is but before that show the alert -"You can enter only manual hours"

```
if(parseFloat(time_compare) >= parseFloat(stopTimer)){
  //$(".end-time-timesheet").trigger("click");
  var count = 0
  if(count == 0){
    alert("You can enter only manual hours.");
    count = count + 1
  }
  if(count == 1){
    clearInterval(handler);
    var isstart1 = 0;
    var ticket_no1 = "";
    if($("#ticket_no").val()!=""){
      ticket_no1 = $("#ticket_no").val();
    }           
    $.ajax({
      async: false,
      type: 'get',
      url: '/check-timesheet-isStart?user_check='+@user_check+'&currentSelectedDate='+currentSelectedDate,
      data: '',
      success: function (data) {
        if(data != ""){ 
          var url = "/saveTimesheet?ajax=1&isstart="+isstart1+"&date="+currentSelectedDate+"&ticket_no="+ticket_no1+"&t="+Date.now();
          $.ajax({                        
            async : false,
            type : 'post',
            url : url,
            success : function (data) {                             
              window.location.href=window.location.href;
              jQuery(".timesheet-wrapper").html(data);
              calculateTotalHour();                           
              //$("#pop-box-over").hide();                            
            }
          });
        }else{
          window.location.href=window.location.href;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: odd code ... `var count = 0
  if(count == 0){
    alert("You can enter only manual hours.");
    count = count + 1
  }
  if(count == 1){` ... is just `alert("You can enter only manual hours.");` with nonsense around it really

Comment: I have tried that code, but it didn't worked..

Comment: well ... it should (of course, there's a `}` near the end you'll need to remove as well ... but really ... the code at the top is nonsense

Comment: Which one to remove ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a difference in pop-up blocker behavior. Turn off Chrome's pop-up blocker and see what happens.

Comment: If  same tab is open, then it showing the alert , but If I am in other tab then it is refreshing the page, due to ajax call, not showing the alert.